# Send push notification with data using JSON

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to send a push notification with some data in it. For example
I send this from parse
`{ "phoneId": "EJw6pFSQNY", "action": "com.parse.starter.UPDATE_STATUS" }`

How can I send it from the android device. I am using the following code

```
JSONObject obj = null;
try {

    obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("phoneId",pass);
    obj.put("action","com.parse.starter.UPDATE_STATUS");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
// Notification for Android users
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", pass);
Log.d("LOG",pass);
push.setQuery(query);
push.setData(obj);
push.setMessage(pass);
push.sendInBackground();
```

And this is the code I use to retrieve the data

```
  JSONObject notificationPayload = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

                id = notificationPayload.getString("phoneId");
```

But this is not working.

Comment: can u pls tell i m  doing same but message is sending successfully from one mobile and it is shown in parse.com as well but i m failed to recieve in another mobile that is target mobile

Comment: http://pastie.org/10224504 @olympus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do both `setData` and `setMessage`. The [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html#setData(org.json.JSONObject)) says that if you call one, you overwrite the other. In your case, calling setMessage will overwrite your setData call.

Comment: @ajma i m using this code but notification not recieved http://pastie.org/10224504